# What are the iOS specifications / guidelines for navigation bar background images?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, user-interface

Does anyone know the iOS image resolutions for navigation bar backgrounds? I’ve found the resolutions for pretty much all the other elements on Apple’s Custom Icon and Image Creation Guidelines page, but I couldn’t seem to find anything for pixel sizes requirements for navigation bar background images (both regular and retina).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The iOS navigation bar is 44 pixels tall and 320 pixels wide. On Retina displays, those numbers are double, at 88 pixels and 640 pixels respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The navigation bar is 44 pixels tall. You can check the dimensions of any iOS UI element by creating one in interface builder and clicking on the size inspector (the ruler).

Answer (score 0):

Note there is an issue I reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175232/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-width-and-insets-of-a-bar-button-item-on-a-navigati). It seems you cannot set width and insets of a bar button item image on a navigation item from within IB size inspector nor programmatically, they simply have no effect. You can do so for a bar button item on the toolbar though. This seems to be a bug.

By the way here is the link to [Apple Icon and Image Creation Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html).

Answer (score -1):

Apple does not support api for setting background image of NavigationBar.
You can only set tintColor.
Or you can subclass and implement the - (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect method.

Comment: This is inaccurate. iOS 5 includes a new set of APIs that allow customization of the appearance of system controls.